# Fragment Transition Animation using Object Animator not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, objectanimator

**I just want to say this isn't a duplicate, this question hasn't been addressed on stack overflow**

I have multiple fragments in the application that the user navigates through.  I had the support library in my code but I have since removed it, when I was using it was I was animating the fragments with  `<translate>` .  I have now changed that to  this works fine if I hard code in the values to and from.  As my app will be used on different screen densities I can't do this.  So after research and tutorials I created my custom FrameLayout as follows:

```
public class CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout{

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


   public float getXFraction() {
        return getX() / getWidth(); // TODO: guard divide-by-zero
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        // TODO: cache width
        final int width = getWidth();
        setX((width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : -9999);
    }
}
```

my animation xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="xFraction"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

and my main activity layout is:

```
<com.axn.test.app.custom.CustomFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I then have the code to set the custom animations:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_in_right, R.animator.fragment_slide_in_right, R.animator.fragment_slide_in_right, R.animator.fragment_slide_out_right);
```

The problem is when I change fragments there is no animation and I get the following in the console:

```
W/PropertyValuesHolder﹕ Method setXFraction() with type float not found on target class class android.widget.RelativeLayout
```

So if anyone has come across this in the past or knows how to fix this issue I'd appreciate it.  in my customFrameLayout `setXFraction(float xFraction)` and  `getXFraction()` are never called so I'm not sure where to go from here...all input greatly appreciated

**EDIT  ====  FRAGMENT LAYOUT ===== **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/show1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/poster1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/poster1"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/poster1Details"
                android:background="@drawable/reflection1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/poster1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/poster1text"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/poster1Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/poster1text"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/episode1"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/show2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/poster2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/poster2"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/poster2Details"
                android:background="@drawable/reflection2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/poster2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/poster2text"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/poster2Title"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/poster2text"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="@string/episode1"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/logos_backgrounds"
      />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/presents"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the layout of your fragment?

Comment: I'll include that in an edit...I have multiple fragments with different layouts

Comment: There you go. You are trying to aninamte a fragment. Not an activity. So your have to add the `CustomFrameLayout` on the fragment you are setting the animations to.

Comment: So instead of my Relative Layout I have my custom frame layout?

Comment: Yes. the error you're getting it's because you are trying to animate that relative layout that is the parent of your fragment. See: `on target class class android.widget.RelativeLayout`?

Comment: ok but then this causes a serious problem with my layouts...as FrameLayout doesn't allow for attributes of Relative Layout, or should I just wrap everything inside the customFrameLayout?

Comment: Then you should think what are you really trying to archive with your current architecture. What do you want to animate. What is a fragment and what is an activity. The difference between both layouts etc etc.

Comment: I am looking to just use my holding activity and animate the transitions of these fragments, slide new one in and previous one out...

Comment: @PedroOliveira can you put as an answer so I can accept?  thank you

Comment: I updated my answer bellow. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to animate a fragment. Not an activity. So you have to add the CustomFrameLayout on the fragment you are setting the animations to. Once your transaction takes place the transaction will animate the values on your fragment's parent and not your activity's. That's why you're getting `Method setXFraction() with type float not found on target class class android.widget.RelativeLayout`. Because the parent of your fragment is a RelativeLayout and it doesn't have the setXFraction method.

Still I will left the rest of the anwser bellow because it might help others.

**in_from_left.xml**

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

**in_from_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1000"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

And my transaction looks like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.in_from_right);
transaction.add(R.id.container,myFragment,"tag");
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for that but the problem there is it's a set from point...where as if I use that there are ui issues, the fragments aren't together while animating

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. And yes that doesn't account into that. However, and like I said, the transition animations will use the fragment's layout and not the activities layout.

Comment: The XML files are wrong because you still use absolute values and it won't work properly.